# jQuery Datatable button expand/collapse all

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatable and I want to add a button for expand/collapse all row of my table. But I have an issue for the expand when I have row already expanded, and I click on the Button expandALL the row that I expand first is collapsed now .. Or if I do the inverse he will be expanded and the other collapse ..

```
function init() {
  $('#btn-show-all-doc').on('click', function() {
                expandCollapseAll();
});
}
function expandCollapseAll() {
        Document.table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');

        }
```

Image
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/QURFM.png

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet on jsfiddle? it would be easier to identify the issue

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how can I manage this because I need to call webservice for this issue.. Because if i have less than 50rows the Expand and Collapse work well .. Just more than 50my issue

Comment: Call the webservice then just use a static table for the demo which has more than 50 rows

Comment: Now I change the code and I remove the loop `Document.table.rows().every(function()..` and I have not now this issue .. But the issue that I have now is : If I expand one row and I after I click on the button for expanding all, the row that I expand first is collapsed now .. Or if I do the inverse he will be expanded and the other collapse .. The code that I use is : `function expandCollapseAll() {
   Document.table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click'); } ` ... Picture in attach